# PHP to take data from WCFM Order meta, and push into AST plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, metadata

While im pretty hopeless at php, i feel like im getting close on this one, i just cant quite lock it in

So we have 2 plugins in the mix here WCFM & AST

In WCFM, a vendor adds a tracking number and carrier this is store in the order meta data with a meta keys of
wcfm_tracking_code
AND
wcfm_tracking_url

i found this hook elesewhere that allows me to fire a set of things to happen, once the tracking has been submitted into the system

```
“wcfm_after_order_mark_shipped” (Parameters -> $order_id, $order_item_id, $tracking_code, $tracking_url)
```

so now i want to take the above 2 order meta datas and push them into another plugin called AST
They code they provide to push data into thier system is:

```
<?php if ( class_exists( 'WC_Advanced_Shipment_Tracking_Actions' ) ) {

$order_id = '123'; //Replace with your order id
$tracking_provider = 'USPS'; //Replace with your shipping provider
$tracking_number = '123123'; //Replace with your tracking number
$date_shipped = '2020-06-22'; ////Replace with your shipped date
$status_shipped = 1; // 0=no,1=shipped,2=partial shipped(if partial shipped order status is enabled)
$sku = 't-shirt,blue-jeans'; //the line item (product) SKU
$qty = '1,1'; //the line item (product) quantity

if ( function_exists( 'ast_insert_tracking_number' ) ) {
    ast_insert_tracking_number( $order_id, $tracking_number, $tracking_provider, $date_shipped, $status_shipped, $sku, $qty );
}
```

}

SO using both codes provided, can anyone show me how i can take the metadata input from WCFM and push it into AST?

Ive hired someone on upwork, and they cant even figure it out, but it seems so straightforward.

This is the code we have,it pushes the data in but it comes in looking like this

[image]

Instead of this like it should

[image]

```
add_action( 'wcfm_after_order_mark_shipped', 'testwr', 99, 6 );
function testwr( $order_id, $order_item_id, $tracking_code, $tracking_url, $product_id, $wcfm_tracking_data ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $data['order_id'] = $order_id;
    $data['tracking_provider'] = $tracking_url; 
    $data['wcfm_tracking_code'] = $wcfm_tracking_data['wcfm_tracking_code'];
    $data['date_shipped'] = $order->order_date;
    $data['status_shipped'] = 1;
    extract($data);
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
        $product = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
        $item_quantity[] = $item->get_quantity();
        $item_sku[] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    if( $item_sku ) {
        $data['sku'] = implode( ",",$item_sku );
    }
    $tracking_url = $tracking_url . "/" . $tracking_code;
    $url = "<a href='".$tracking_url."'>test</a>";
    $data['qty'] = implode( ",",$item_quantity );
    $test = ast_insert_tracking_number( $order_id, $tracking_url, $tracking_url, $date_shipped, $status_shipped, $sku, $qty);
    var_dump($test);
    print_r($tracking_code);
    print_r($data);
    print_r($wcfm_tracking_data);
    var_dump($order_item_id);
    //ast_insert_tracking_number
    die();
}
```

Kudos to anyone willing to give this a try and some time

Regards